# AS3 using the loader CLASS with .content

Tags: actionscript-3, loader

I've been working on a program, but currently I'm stuck.

My problem is the `.content` statement in my script. Since I'm loading a PNG from the web I have the Local playback security set to "Access network only". When I load pictures locally (of course with settings at "Access local files only", and local URLRequests) the program works just fine, but when loading from the web the `.content` makes my program stop, I've found this out with lots of testing. It seems the `.content` only works when the SWF file only uses local requests, is this correct?

I know that I can use `addChild(loader)`, but I need to get the PNG file out of the loader so that I can turn it into a bitmap and edit it. Any ideas? The script is below.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader;
var ar:Array = [];
var teller:Number = 0;

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, paste);
knapp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, neste);

function paste(evt) {
    ar[teller] = loader.content;
    ar[teller].x = ar[teller].width*teller;
    addChild(ar[teller]);
}

function neste(evt) {
    teller ++
    loader.load( new URLRequest ("http://www.minecraft.net/skin/Notch.png"));
}

loader.load( new URLRequest ("http://www.minecraft.net/skin/Notch.png"));
```

Comment: Can I see your full class code, so I could make a research?

Comment: It's a bit complex, but if you want to see it, i have the fla file:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/37542813/Ranking.fla
if you try to run it in flash, you will see that it works, while in a swf it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-domain policies prohibits image data manipulation for images loaded from another domain than the one the swf file is loaded from:

http://www.dwuser.com/flashslideshow/v4/help/advanced_topics/understanding_flash_player_cross_domain_loading_restrictions.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been looking into that, but still I wonder. How come I get the png and can add it to stage if I'm supposed not to get the picture at all? After all I first expirienced this when I tried to load my swf file to a server, localy it worked just fine

Comment: I agree that it is not entirely clear why you are allowed to display images loaded from another domain, but not allowed to get to, and possibly tamper with, the bitmap data of that image. Regarding it working locally, during development, I believe that is true for other cross-domain restrictions too, that it will work when run locally, but not when the swf is loaded from a web server.